# Read Excel or OpenOffice (.ods) files Using ActiveXObject (JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, asp.net, excel, openoffice-calc, activexobject

In My system i don't have MS office,i have Openoffice. Here my Requirement is i want to read .xls .xlsx and .ods files with ActiveXObject (JavaScript).By using below code i read only .xls files only.here how can i read all types of excel files with ActiveXobjects?

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    function ReadMyFile()
    {
        var ControlCn = new ActiveXObject("ADODB.Connection");
        var Conn = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source = D:\\DailyReport.ods; Persist Security Info=False;Extended Properties=Excel 8.0;";
        ControlCn.Open(Conn);
        var rs = new ActiveXObject("ADODB.Recordset");
        var SQL = "select * from [Sheet1$]";
        rs.Open(SQL, ControlCn);
        if(rs.bof)
        {
            document.write('No Data Avaliable');
        } 

        if(!rs.bof)
        {
            rs.MoveFirst()
            while(!rs.eof)
            {
                for(var i=0; i!= rs.fields.count; ++i)
                {                            
                    document.write(rs.fields(i).value + ", ");
                }
                document.write("<br />");
                rs.MoveNext()
            }
        }
        rs.Close();
        ControlCn.Close(); 

    }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <input type="button" value="Click To Read Your File" onClick="ReadMyFile()">
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

To create an ActiveXObject that automates OpenOffice Calc:

```
var objServiceManager= new ActiveXObject("com.sun.star.ServiceManager");
```

See https://www.openoffice.org/udk/common/man/tutorial/office_automation.html.

I do not think that this object will handle executing SQL commands.